# WordPress: How to order custom posts, on their archive page, using two meta keys?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've created a custom post type "prodotti" with two meta keys; **I want to see the archive page ordered by these two meta keys** but I can't manage to do it. Let me explain.

#### I created a custom post type "prodotti"

```
add_action( 'init', 'fawola_register_product', 0 );
function fawola_register_product()
{
    $labels = array(
        // ...
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Prodotto', 'fawola' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Prodotti proposti', 'fawola' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array(),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 20,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-products',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'prodotti', $args );
}
```

#### I created two booleans meta keys "prodotti_offerta" and "prodotti_offerta"

Using the [Metabox](https://metabox.io/) library.

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'mytheme_prodotti_register_meta_boxes' );
function mytheme_prodotti_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes )
{
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title'      => 'Visibilità del prodotto',
        'post_types' => 'prodotti',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name'      => 'Top',
                'id'        => 'prodotti_top',
                'type'      => 'radio',
                'inline'    => true,
                'std'       => 'no',
                'options'   => array(
                    'no' => 'No',
                    'si' => 'Si',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'name'      => 'Offerta',
                'id'        => 'prodotti_offerta',
                'type'      => 'radio',
                'inline'    => true,
                'std'       => 'no',
                'options'   => array(
                    'no' => 'No',
                    'si' => 'Si',
                ),
            ),
        )
    );
    return $meta_boxes;     
}
```

#### I want this thing to happen

If I go to page .../prodotti, I want to see all custom posts but first I want to see the ones with "prodotti_offerta"=="si" or "prodotti_top"=="si"

#### I've tried to set a pre_get_posts function

```
function mytheme_category_top_offerta( $query )
{
    if( 
        ( is_tax('tipi') or is_tax('colori') or is_tax('materiali') or is_tax('stili') or is_post_type_archive('prodotti') )
        and !is_admin() and $query->is_main_query()
    )
    {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'prodotti_offerta' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mytheme_category_top_offerta' );
```

#### Unfortunally it doesn't work

- I'm not able to order ALSO by the second meta key ("prodotti_top")
- If a custom post doens't have any value set for "prodotti_offerta" or "prodotti_top", it don't show up in the list